# Javascript: Find every instance of strings between two strings

Tags: javascript, string, search, replace

I have a string which contains a word encased in @- and -@ like so: This @-book-@ is created by author @-gameauthor-@.

I need a function that will find all the instances of words in between that encasement and return it. It works well if there is only one word encased in it. But if there are two words it will return everything in between the first @- and the last -@. So instead of returning book and gameauthor, it returns: -book-@ is created by author @-gameauthor-

I wrote this function and code, how can I improve it:

```
function findBetween(text, firststring, secondstring) {


    //Function to text between two strings.
    var firstvariable = firststring;
    var secondvariable = secondstring;
    var text = text;

    var regExString = new RegExp("(?:" + firstvariable + ")((.[\s\S]*))(?:" + secondvariable + ")", "g"); 

    var strResult = regExString.exec(text);
if (strResult != null) {
    return strResult[1];
    }
}

var str = "This @-book-@ is created by author @-gameauthor-@.";

var test = findBetween(str, "@-", "-@");

alert(test);
```

EDIT: Here is an updated code using the solution below:

```
function replaceAll(str, find, replace) {
  return str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
}   

var book = "Moby Dick";
var gameauthor = "Joey DiPerla";

var str = "This @-book-@ is created by author @-gameauthor-@.";

var myArray = str.split("@");

var len = myArray.length;

for(let i = len-1;i>=0;i--){  
   myArray[i] = myArray[i].replace(/-/g, '');
   if(i%2 == 0) {
       myArray.splice(i,1)

    if ( myArray[i] !== undefined) {

        var find = "@-" + myArray[i] + "-@";
        var replace = eval(myArray[i]);

        str = replaceAll(str, find, replace);
    }

   }
}

alert(str);
```

Comment: That's called "greedy matching". Turn it off by using [the syntax for that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Quantifiers#Types). Also, take advantage of template literals: ```new RegExp(`(?:${firststring})((.[\s\S]*))(?:${secondstring})`, "g");```. No need for `"..." + "..."` in modern JS.

Comment: I think you are looking for `@-(.[^]*?)-@` and get the value of capturing group 1 https://regex101.com/r/PENNSD/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to use the split function to break the string down to an array of strings and then remove the '-'.  Finally, remove the elements not wanted with splice.

```js
var str = "This @-book-@ is created by author @-gameauthor-@.";

var myArray = str.split("@");

var len = myArray.length;

for(let i = len-1;i>=0;i--){  
   myArray[i] = myArray[i].replace(/-/g, '');
   if(i%2 == 0) myArray.splice(i,1);
}

console.log(myArray)
```

Comment: I used this as my solution. See updated code in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Although you don't need to escape your `\` in RegExp literals, you do need to `\\` in RegExp strings... but that's only part of your issue:

```js
function findBetween(str, start, end = null){
  let s = start, e = end;
  if(e === null)e = s;
  const x = new RegExp(s+'[^'+e+']+'+e, 'g'), m = str.match(x), r = new RegExp('^'+s+'|'+e+'$', 'g');
  return m.map(s=>s.replace(r, ''));
}
console.log(findBetween('This @-book-@ is created by author @-gameauthor-@.', '@-', '-@'));
```